# Getting a SyntaxError in try:except (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi so I'm really new to Python and I have a little question.

In my code:

```
from collections import Counter
```

try:
    while True:

```
    name1 = input ("your name")
list(name1)
name1len = len(name1)

name2 = input ("other one's name")
list(name2)
name2len = len(name2)

if name1len > 10:
    print ("name is too long")
    break 
if name2len > 10:
    print ("name is too long")
    break
a1 = (name1[0][0])
a2 = (name2[0][0])
if set(a1) & set(a1) == set(a2):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")

a3 = (name1[1][0])
a4 = (name2[1][0])
if set(a3) & set(a3) == set(a4):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")

a5 = (name1[2][0])
a6 = (name2[2][0])
if set(a5) & set(a5) == set(a6):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")
a7 = (name1[3][0])
a8 = (name2[3][0])
if set(a7) & set(a7) == set(a8):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")

a9 = (name1[4][0])
a10 = (name2[4][0])
if set(a9) & set(a9) == set(a10):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")
a11 = (name1[5][0])
a12 = (name2[5][0])
if set(a11) & set(a11) == set(a12):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")
a13 = (name1[6][0])
a14 = (name2[6][0])
if set(a13) & set(a13) == set(a14):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")
a15 = (name1[7][0])
a16 = (name2[7][0])
if set(a15) & set(a15) == set(a16):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")
a17 = (name1[8][0])
a18 = (name2[8][0])
if set(a17) & set(a18) == set(a19):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")
a19 = (name1[9][0])
a20 = (name2[9][0])
if set(a19) & set(a19) == set(a20):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")
a21 = (name1[10][0])
a22 = (name2[10][0])
if set(a21) & set(a21) == set(a22):
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("none")

    except (IndexError):
    pass
```

and in the end at the very bottom, it keeps on giving me this error:

File "dr.luvtest.py", line 106
except (IndexError):
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] to  make sure your indentation is correct.

Comment: `except` has to be on the same indentation level as `try`.

Comment: Also, what is this code even supposed to do? Compare the difference between two strings? `name1[0][0]` is the same as `name1[0]` because it's the first character of a string

Comment: This is a mess. You need to distill down the *specific* things to `try` and the specific response if the try block does not work. I think you probably had an index error at some point and then wrapped a bunch of code inside of `try / except` to make that go away. Now you have a bigger problem that is only solved by rethinking your original code.

Comment: If indentation is not the issue, like @cricket_007 and @klaus-d suggested, then maybe it is a python version issue.
what python version are you using?
If you're using python 2.7.x while using python 3 print function then you need to import it via future.
Meaning `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @ge7600 the print statements look fine.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all your help it was something to do with the indenting at the bottom and yes this Python 3. I fixed the thing with the [0] instead of having [0] [0]! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `try & except` functions, you need to you that first part, the `try`. In your code there is no `try:` which is why the `except` is causing issues.

However every time I try to fix one issue, other one pops up. However Python won't even run your code if the syntax is incorrect.

In order to fix the syntax error,

Change

```
else:
    print ("none")

except IndexError:
    pass
```

To

Wrap the whole thing in a `try` statement,
then the `except` will catch an `IndexError`

Comment: Hey thanks man this really helped and now the code is working! It was with the indenting at the end. Also in the start I put **try:** on line 2 and then a new line and then an indent and then put **while True:**  ! Thanks a bunch!